# Why am I getting all goroutines are asleep when I close the channel after waiting?

Tags: go, concurrency, deadlock, channel

Following is the code:

```
func makeData() map[string][]Data {
    m := make(map[string][]Data)
    s := "abcdefghijklmno"

    for i, c := range s {
        data := []Data{
            {value: "hey_" + string(c), id: i * i},
            {value: "hello_" + string(c) + string(c), id: i + i},
            {value: "bye_" + string(c), id: i + 1},
        }
        m[strconv.Itoa(i)] = data
    }

    return m
}

func process(key string, value []Data) (*Result, error) {
    if key == "hey_a" {
        return nil, errors.New("error")
    }

    res := Result{data: Data{value: "hi", id: 0}, id: 1}
    return &res, nil
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    m := makeData()
    errg := new(errgroup.Group)

    mapChan := make(chan StringAndData)
    sliceChan := make(chan *Result)

    for key, value := range m {
        key := key
        value := value

        errg.Go(func() error {
            return func(key string, value []Data) error {
                res, err := process(key, value)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                if res == nil {
                    return nil
                }

                if res.data.id == 1 {
                    mapChan <- StringAndData{
                        str:  key,
                        data: res.data,
                    }
                    return nil
                }

                sliceChan <- res
                return nil

            }(key, value)
        })
    }

    if err := errg.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("success")
    }

    close(mapChan)
    close(sliceChan)

    for ac := range mapChan {
        fmt.Println(ac.str)
    }
}

type Data struct {
    value string
    id    int
}

type Result struct {
    data Data
    id   int
}

type StringAndData struct {
    str  string
    data Data
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tRb0dvo0Lca)

I am getting `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` but I am closing the channels after `errg.Wait()` and am not able to understand the reason.

I am trying to print values that I get from the channel after closing them using `range`.

I am new to channels and concurrency with go and would appreciate any help!

**Edit**
Added all the code from the playground link

Comment: Where do `m` and `errg` come from? Please post the minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: @jub0bs please take a look at the playground link. It is `errorGroup`

Comment: Is that minimal, though? Also, SO questions are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: @jub0bs updated with more code

Comment: Basically it means that by the time `errg.Wait()` had finished, there remain outstanding goroutines (waiting on some resources). Go detects all these goroutines (including main, which waits on `mapChan`) are blocked on some resources. The first thing to do is to drop using `errgroup`: please do not fall into the trap of using fancy stuff until you're comfortable with the basics. Make your code work using plain channels (and may be `sync.WaitGroup`).

Comment: @kostix I am using `errgroup` since that satisfies one of my requirements; I need to end all the goroutines asap if I find a single error from any of them. Is this an issue with `errgroup` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, two things can cause a deadlock:

- `errg.Wait()` blocks the execution of the main goroutine until all initialized goroutines are finished. However, each goroutine is blocked when trying to write to `mapChan`, because you never get to read from it (because it is below the `errg.Wait()`).
- You never read from `sliceChan`, so that is a potential deadlock right there.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/_DqYX6lG4S6) is the link to the modified Playground code, but most of the changes are in the `main` function.

```
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    m := makeData()
    errg := new(errgroup.Group)

    mapChan := make(chan StringAndData)
    sliceChan := make(chan *Result)
    mapDone := make(chan bool)
    sliceDone := make(chan bool)

    go func(){
        for ac := range mapChan {
            fmt.Println(ac.str)
        }
        mapDone <- true
    }()
    go func(){
        for ac := range sliceChan {
            fmt.Println(ac)
        }
        sliceDone <- true
    }()

    for key, value := range m {
        key := key
        value := value

        errg.Go(func() error {
            return func(key string, value []Data) error {
                res, err := process(key, value)
                if err != nil {
                    return err
                }
                if res == nil {
                    return nil
                }

                if res.data.id == 1 {
                    mapChan <- StringAndData{
                        str:  key,
                        data: res.data,
                    }
                    return nil
                }

                sliceChan <- res
                return nil

            }(key, value)
        })
    }

    if err := errg.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("success")
    }

    close(mapChan)
    close(sliceChan)
    <-mapDone
    <-sliceDone
    fmt.Println("finished")

}
```

Basically, I changed how the values are read from `mapChan` and `sliceChan` channels. This is done in separate goroutines, so reading from these channels is not blocked.

The `mapDone` and `sliceDone` channels are added just to make sure all of the data is read before the `main` goroutine finishes.